# Multiple nest structure for lme()

Tags: r, mixed-model, sas, lme4-nlme

I want to build a mixed-effects model with multiple nest structure in R. For example, month nested in year, day nested in year and year. Response variable Y is temperature and predictor variable X is time. The following SAS code can give me exactly what I need.

```
proc mixed data=dataset;
 class year month day;
 model Y=X;
 random day(year) month(year) year;
 run;
```

However, when I use lme(), I do not know how to set up this structure. It should be something like

```
fitted.model <- lme(Y~X, random=list(~1|year/day, ~1|year/month, ~1|year), data=dataset)
```

The above command does not work. If I wrote as

```
fitted.model <- lme(Y~X, random=list(~1|year, ~1|month, ~1|day), data=dataset)
```

I will get the nested random effect year/month/day which is what I do not want to have.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you mean when you say it does not work in your first example?

Comment: @ Matthew George Barstead , it will report an error. I do not have the data on this computer. So I cannot produce the error message. Acutally, when I check the help file for lme(), it also shows that "random" parameter does not support that kind format of random effect in the first example.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use `lmer`? There it would be `lmer(Y~X + (1|year/month/day), data=dataset`. Not sure about `lme`.

Comment: @ amoeba, thank you for asking. Actually, I am fitting a generalized mixed effects model here. I tried many method, only glmmPQL() from MASS converge for my data. From help file, glmmPQL() is based on lme(), so I need to use random option to set up the random effect structure instead of using the formula in the lmer().

Comment: So are you saying that you already tried `glmer()` in the `lme4` package and it didn't converge? If not `glmer()` should work using the syntax provided by @amoeba. You'll just need to specify the link function in the `family=` argument.

Comment: @MatthewGeorgeBarstead, yes, you are correct. I tried glmer() and get the warning message said it does not converge. I also have a little concern about the syntax provided by amoeba, does it include the nest structure month/day? The month/day structure should not be in my model. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding `lmer` syntax, `(1|year/month/day)` is equivalent to `(1|year) + (1|year:month) + (1|year:month:day)`. If for some reason you want `(1|year) + (1|year:month) + (1|year:day)`, then you can write it as such. I cannot really imagine a case when this would be more appropriate but anyway. As I said, I cannot help with `lme`, you should search for how to specify crossed random effects there and then use consider the terms listed above as crossed.

Comment: @amoeba, got it. Thank you very much for your help on the lmer/glmer syntax.